# Can't perform any unit tests for firestore security rules with jest

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I am new to testing and I am looking at firebase documentation for testing security rules, but it's very limiting and has no information.

this is my security rule that I want to test:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow read: if belongsTo(userId) && isLoggedIn()
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null
  }
  function belongsTo(userId){
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
  }
```

This is my test file:

```
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

// Assuming a Firestore app and the Firestore emulator for this example
import { setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

test("this is test, checks that only authenticated user can see their data", async () => {
  let testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: "myproject-ce845",
    firestore: {
      rules: readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
      port: 8080,
    },
  });
  const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice");
  await assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), "/users/alice"));
});
```

this is the error that I'm getting:

```
    {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Error compiling rules:\nL29:5 missing ';' at 'return'\nL33:3 mismatched input '}' expecting {'&&', ',', '.', '==', '>', '>=', '[', '<', '<=', '-', '%', '!=', '||', '+', ']', '\/', '*', '?', 'in', 'is'}","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing (`INVALID_ARGUMENT`) is a syntax error with your rules. I’m not sure if it’s a typo on your question or not, but your rules are missing a closing bracket at the end of the file:

```
rules_version = '2'; // <= Also the rule syntax version should be added
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow read: if belongsTo(userId) && isLoggedIn();
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }
  function belongsTo(userId){
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  }
} // <= This closing bracket is missing
```

In addition to that, I think it’s important to read [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5825) if you are attempting to follow the documentation about building [unit tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#run_local_unit_tests_with_the_version_9_javascript_sdk) that targets your rules. This issue affects using ES6 modules, and using the modular syntax will lead to this error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

A workaround shown in the issue is to create your tests using CommonJS syntax, or try with the V8 SDK. I went ahead and built an example based on the workaround shown:

```js
const { initializeTestEnvironment, assertSucceeds, assertFails} = require("@firebase/rules-unit-testing");
const { doc, getDoc } = require("firebase/firestore");
const fs = require('fs');

const testRules = async () => {
    const testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
        projectId: projectIDStr,
        firestore: {
            rules: fs.readFileSync(rulesPath, "utf8"),
            host: "localhost", // Required to run in the emulator in case it’s not automatically detected!
            port: 8080
        },
    });
    const context = await testEnv.authenticatedContext("id_alice");
    return await assertSucceeds(getDoc(doc(context.firestore(), "users", "id_alice")));
}

test("Simulated read is allowed by Firebase rules", async () => {
    await expect(testRules()).resolves.toBeDefined(); // assertSucceeds promise is resolved since rules allowed it
});
```

This test aligns more with your rules, as only authenticated users are able to see their data.

Comment: @LukasVis I edited this answer in case you are still having issues